# Use enum in react select option

Tags: reactjs, lodash

I have this enum:

```
const SPORTS = {
    FOOTBALL: 0,
    GOLF: 1,
    TENNIS: 2
};
```

I'm trying to use those values in a react select dropdown using lodash's [forIn](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#forIn)

```
<select onChange={(event) => this.update(event, sport.id)}>
  {_.forIn(SPORTS, (key, value) => {
    {
      <option value={key}>{value}</option>;
    }
  })}
</select>;
```

But am getting the error:

```
Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child
```

EDIT:

Changing to _.map works but am now seeing another issue.

Before I was manually adding all the options like which worked fine:

```
<option value={0}>FOOTBALL</option>;
<option value={1}>GOLF</option>;
<option value={2}>TENNIS</option>;
```

Now using the map I get this error:

```
Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop
```

Now when my select boxes render they are empty but I'm not sure why.

Comment: `forIn` returns an object, not a component.

Comment: You are returning object literal instead of JSX element. Use `_.forIn(SPORTS, (key, value) => (<option value={key}>{value}</option>))`

Comment: @nbokmans `forIn` returns the object that it was given. It just iterates over it, doesn't perform a mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_.forIn()` function returns the iterated object, use `_.map()` instead:

```
<select onChange={(event) => this.update(event, sport.id)}>
  {_.map(SPORTS, (value, key) => (
    <option value={key} key={key}>{value}</option>;
  ))}
</select>;
```

Comment: Thanks! I just added an edit as I'm still having an issue doing it this way

Comment: It was missing the `key` property. See edit.

Comment: Thanks, the exception about the key has gone but now my select boxes are empty and when I click the dropdown there are no options there. Is there any reason you can think of why that is?

Comment: You need to return the component as well. Updated.

Comment: did you figure this out ?- I'm trying to do this with chakra-react-select